# create custom org export function

Tags: org-export

I'm interested in modifying the functionality for how org exports to markdown/html. What I want to achieve is hanging indents in exported poetry, and a decent way to achieve this is with `<span></span>` tags. so i would like to be able to export a verse block to something like:

```
<p class="verse-hanging">
<span class="hanging">poem verse 1</span><br />
<span class="hanging">poem verse 2</span><br />
</p>
```

rather than

```
<p class="verse">
poem verse 1<br />
poemverse 2<br />
</p>
```

[what ever the class names have to be, the only need i think is for them to not be `verse`, so the two can be styled differently.]

i have seen `org-html-verse-block`, i could rewrite it to this end, but i'm not sure how i would go about using it in an export.

the tags should be optional for verse blocks.

can i modify export functions or might this be more of a dangerous rabbit hole that i would never emerge out of?

Comment: Rewriting `org-html-verse-block` is the way to go, but you need to define a `derived` exporter. See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/71803/how-to-use-an-org-mode-documents-title-in-the-latex-export-headers/71808#71808 for an example - although the context is different, the implemenation is going to be very similar.

Answer (score 1):

With this `org` snippet

```
#+begin_verse

Nulla exercitation incididunt ullamco
        Eiusmod commodo eu labore occaecat ut non
Voluptate elit, eiusmod do
        Est dolor ullamco lorem pariatur esse duis

#+end_verse
```

to get this on html export

```html
<p class="verse">
<span class="verse-line"><br /></span>
<span class="verse-line">Nulla exercitation incididunt ullamco<br /></span>
<span class="verse-line">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;Eiusmod commodo eu labore occaecat ut non<br /></span>
<span class="verse-line">Voluptate elit, eiusmod do<br /></span>
<span class="verse-line">&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;Est dolor ullamco lorem pariatur esse duis<br /></span>
<span class="verse-line"><br /></span>
</p>
```

install this

```lisp
(require 'rx)

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-verse-block-functions
             'my-org-export-filter-verse-block-functions)

(defun my-org-export-filter-verse-block-functions (text backend _info)
  (cl-case backend
    (html
     ;; Special processing for HTML
     (with-temp-buffer
       (insert text)
       (pop-to-buffer (current-buffer))
       (let* ((start (progn
                       (goto-char (point-min))
                       (when (re-search-forward (rx (and "<p" (one-or-more (not ">")) ">")))
                         (insert "\n")
                         (point))))
              (end (progn
                     (goto-char (point-max))
                     (when (re-search-backward (rx "</p>"))
                       (prog1 (point)
                         (insert "\n"))))))
         (narrow-to-region start end)
         ;; Remove leading empty lines
         (goto-char (point-min))
         (skip-chars-forward "\r\n")
         (delete-region (point-min) (point))
         ;; Remove Trailing empty lines
         (goto-char (point-max))
         (skip-chars-backward "\r\n")
         (delete-region (point-max) (point))
         ;; Surround each line with `<span class="verse-line"> </span>'
         (goto-char (point-min))
         (while (not (eobp))
           (insert (format "<span class=\"%s\">" "verse-line"))
           (goto-char (point-at-eol))
           (insert "</span>")
           (forward-line 1))
         (widen)
         (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)))))
    (t
     ;; No special processing for non-HTML backends
     text)))
```